# Putting a website in a directory above the public_html,Can search engines find it?,Is this website crawled by search engines?,What is the solution?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, search-engine, web-hosting

I have a Linux web host and I have added some other domains beside the main domains,as add-ons domains.

I have created a directory beyond the main public_html directory,
for each of them,and all of thier contents are in those directories,you can open the websites,by typing their URL in browser,but nearly more than two month after the creation of the websites;

after searching their URL in Google,nothing is showed up in the search results,for example if you search the "yahoo.com" phrase in google,the number one result would be the http://yahoo.com result,but I assume the search engines could not crawl a website in a directory beyond the public_html,is this true?

what is the solution?

Please note that I am not talking about Google specifically,I am asking about all of the Bots on the web.

and about the directory,I meant for example in the website1,website2,website3 directories.

```
   /website1
   /website2
   /website3
   /mail
   /logs
   /includes
   /public_html
       /images
       /admin
       /users
```

Thanks

Websites URLs:

http://pooryekta.ir

http://makethefuture.ir

http://iabec.ir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ and log in
2. If you haven't already, add and verify the site with the "Add a Site" button
3. Click on the site name for the one you want to manage
4. Click Health -> Fetch as Google
5. Optional: if you want to do a specific page only, type in the URL
6. Click Fetch
7. Click Submit to Index
8. Select either "URL" or "URL and all linked pages"
9. Click OK and you're done.

Comment: thanks for the answer,please note that I don't targeted google.com,specifically,I am asking about all the bots on the web.